# How can I get the cumulative width of a list of components?

Tags: reactjs

I have a list of "selections" that are displayed using a  component. I need to find the rendered width of all these selections. My template looks like this:

```
{props.selections.map((chip: SelectOptionType) => {
   return (
      <Chip text={chip.label} />
   )
}
```

Typically, in a non-React application, I'd probably put a class on the `<Chip />` and use jquery to select elements of that class name, then loop over them and just sum the widths together:

```
let sum: number = 0;
$(".someClassName").forEach(($el) => sum += $el.offsetWidth);
```

I know the suggested way of doing something similar to this is using refs, but it seems you cant create an array of refs. I tried doing something like this:

```
{props.selections.map((chip: SelectOptionType, index: number) => {
   chipsRefs[index] = React.createRef<HTMLDivElement>();
   return (
      <div ref={chipsRefs[index]}>
         <Chip text={chip.label} />
      </div>
   )
}
```

But as I quickly learned each Ref inside `chipsRefs` ended up with a `null` `current`.

Now I'm a bit at a loss for this and have tried finding examples of this use case but have come up empty.

Comment: Hey @Danny any luck on implementing this?

Comment: Appreciate these suggestions. Looks like @bkm412 nailed it for me. Not sure if the other suggestion works as I went with the shorter of the two first and it seemed to do exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this ?

```
ref={ref => {
   chipsRefs[index] = ref
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try doing something like this: https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-haibt-zeb8m

```
import React from "react";

class Selections extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this._nodes = new Map();
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.checkNodes();
  }

  checkNodes = () => {
    let totalWidth = 0;
    Array.from(this._nodes.values())
      .filter(node => node != null)
      .forEach(node => {
        totalWidth = totalWidth + node.offsetWidth;
      });

    console.log(totalWidth);
  };
  render() {
    const { selections } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        {selections.map((value, i) => (
          <div key={i} ref={c => this._nodes.set(i, c)}>
            {value}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Selections;
```

- The function we defined in the `ref` prop is executed at time of
  `render`.
- In the `ref` call-back function, `ref={c => this._nodes.set(i, c)}`
  we pass in the index (i) provided by `.map()` and the html element
  (c) that is provided by the `ref` prop, in this case the `div` itself.
- `this._nodes.set(i, c)` will create a new key-value pair in our
  this._nodes iterable, one pair for each div we created. Now we have recorded HTML elements (nodes) to work with that contain all the methods we need to calculate the `totalWidth` of your rendered list.

Lastly in `checkNodes()` we get the `.offsetWidth` of each node to get our totalWidth.